# Compiler generating invalid object file

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, linker-errors, c++builder-5

I am working on merging some new trunk code into a feature branch on one of our large legacy projects.  This project is written in C++ using C++Builder 5.0.  We also use TwineCompile 3 to speed up our build times.

After the merge, I now sometimes get the following error when compiling:

```
[ilink32 Error] Unresolved external '__fastcall TPrintTickÜ©  ::Add(int, int, int, bool, TTicketType, int, bool, bool, bool)' referenced from C:\PROJECTS\PRODUCT\V3.12.X\SOURCE\OBJ\PROCESSOR.OBJ
```

This error only shows up when doing a release build with compiler optimizations turned off (which is how we typically release our code).  If I re-enable compiler optimizations, or if I do a debug build, the error does not appear.  Additionally, if I disable TwineCompile, the problem disappears.

Running TDump on the 'processor.obj' object file shows that it has a reference to an external function TPrintTickÜ©  ::Add.  This function should actually be TPrintTicketQueue::Add.  File processor.cpp contains the following code in one of the functions:

```
PrintTicketQueue.Add(/*parameters here*/);
```

For reference, file printTicketQueue.h (which is included by processor.cpp) has the following code:

```
class TPrintTicketQueue
{
    public:
          /* Some more code here */

        void __fastcall Add(int jobID, int ticketID, int numID, bool labelPrint, TTicketType type, int count = 1, bool remote = false, bool print = true, bool printLabelOnly = false);
};

extern TPrintTicketQueue PrintTicketQueue;
```

To further confuse matters, if I attempt to create a local pointer to a TPrintTicketObject in *any* function in processor.cpp, I get the following error:

```
[C++ Error] processor.cpp(291, 18): E2451 Undefined symbol 'TPrintTicketQueue'
```

Despite knowing that printTicketQueue.h has been included in processor.cpp, and thus TPrintTicketQueue should be defined.

I'm at a loss to explain what is happening here.  Has anyone encountered a similar problem with C++Builder 5.0 or TwineCompile?  Is there any way to solve or work around this problem?

Comment: Sounds like a bug in TwineCompiler.  You should [file a bug report](http://www.jomitech.com/bnf.php?p=TwineCompile4) with its author.